# How to order list on Data Validation

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, transpose, flatten

Is it possible to change the order on Data Validation?

The data i want to use is something like this:

[image]

But data validation show the order from left to right then down. Can the order change to top to bottom then right?

Comment: You may try to `TRANSPOSE` the original dataset in another sheet and refer to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directly in data validation its not possible. you can achieve this with helper column tho.

```
=SORT(FLATTEN(A:C))
```